# Trying to build my own strstr() function in c?

Tags: c, while-loop, function-definition, strstr

I'm trying to build my `strstr()` function, it's look all fine
but when I execute the code it return nothing ;

This is my function :

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* ft_strstr(char *str, char *to_find) {
  char *a;
  char *b;

  b = to_find;
  if (!*b)
    return (char*) str;
  while (*str) {
    if (*str != *b)
      continue;
    a = str;
    while (1) {
      if (!*b)
        return (char*) str;
      if (*a++ != *b++)
        break;
    }
    str++;
    b = to_find;
  }
  return (NULL);
}

int main() {
  char string[] = "Hello from morroco";
  char find[] = "from";
  ft_strstr(string, find);
  printf("%s", find);
  return 0;
}
```

I don't know what.  I have to try to fix it cause it looks all fine for me.

Comment: OT: Regarding `return (char *)str;`... If `str` already have the type `char *`, there's just no need to do an explicit conversion to the same type.

Comment: Please format your code properly. Readable code is very important, especially for beginners.

Comment: The code doesn't modify the string pointed to by the `to_find` argument. Why should `find` in the `main` function change? You seem to have some basic misunderstandings about both the [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) function as well as the basics of C.

Comment: can you explain more please ?

Comment: At a glance you seem to have some 2-3 bugs caused by sloppy formatting alone...

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? And no, it does not look fine at all.

Comment: The function *does* return a value but you're not using it. Instead you're simply printing the `find` input string.

Comment: What *exactly* do you expect to happen when you reach `continue;`? What situation will you be in when you come to `if(*str != *b)` again? How is it different from last time you got there?

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in this if statement

```
if(*str != *b)
    continue;
```

the pointer `str` is not increased in this case and as a result the loop will be infinite.

instead of the while loop it is better to use a for loop as

```
for ( ; *str; ++str )
```

or the while loop can look like

```
while (*str)
{
    if( *str == *b )
    {
        a = str;
        while(1)
        {
            if (!*b )
                return (char *)str;
            if (*a++ != *b++)
                break;
        }
    }
    str++;
    b = to_find;
}
```

Also it seems you mean

```
char *pos = ft_strstr(string , find);
if ( pos ) printf("%s", pos);
```

instead of

```
ft_strstr(string , find);
printf("%s", find);
```

Pay attention to that the function should be declared like

```
char * ft_strstr( const char *str, const char *to_find);
```

And using such castings like

```
return (char *)str;
```

makes sense if the parameter `str` has the type `const char *` as it should have.

Comment: Thank you vlad , but in this subject for loop not allowed , cause of that i have to use while but i incremenet str++ in the last of the first while loop and i  tried to stock the function in *p and print it with condition but the output still the same ,

Comment: i have to notice that i can't declare the params in the str function as a const

Comment: @OmarGhazi There s nothing prevents you to declare the parameters with the qualifer const. Also the variables a and b must be declared with the qualifier const.

Comment: @OmarGhazi — why can't you declare function parameters as `const`?  Why is your "teacher" abusing the language so?  It bodes ill for you — you should be being taught how to write good C code, and good C code uses `const` whenever sensible.  Are you also constrained to C90?  If so, you have to start worrying about the standard of education you are receiving.

Comment: @OmarGhazi restrictions concerning `for` and `const` deserve to be in the question.

Comment: @OmarGhazi a for loop is nothing more than a glorified while loop. You can easily transform any for loop into a while loop: `for(a;b;c) d` boils down to: `a; while (b) {d; c;}`.

Comment: @OmarGhazi if you're worried about `const` just drop them. At your level it's not really that important. But eventually you should use `const` properly, your teacher will hopefully introduce this concept sooner or later.